# Promise reject giving me an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Can someone explain to me why what I am doing is wrong? How do I solve this problem the right way?

I have this code to execute a trade:

```
async function limitOrder(keys, symbol, type, quantity, price, waitResult) {

var client = await loadKeys(keys);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.newOrder({
        symbol: symbol,
        side: type, //BUY OR SELL
        type: 'LIMIT',
        quantity: quantity,
        price: price,
        timeInForce: "GTC",
        newOrderRespType: 'RESULT'
    }).then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        resolve({order: response, price: response.price, quantity: response.origQty}); //return back the order ID
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err); //print error if any
        reject(err);
    });
});

}
```

This is how I wrote my Promise function for the first time, and I am getting an error in the `reject(err)` line. So if the order executes correctly, the `resolve()` does return back the order to the function that's calling this one. But if the it reaches the catch block, the error is printed. However, the `reject` line gives me this error instead:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

What I want to do is return the error and handle it in another function (that's calling this one).

Comment: The consumer of `limitOrder` should handle the error, which appears not to be happening. Also, you should avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern

Comment: Add code for consumer of limitOrder method

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0):

In the executor of the new Promise returned by `limitOrder`, there is a promise chain with the value of the promise returned by `catch`. The chain does not have any further promises in it, nor can any be added (the promise chain is not visible outside of `limitOrder`).

When an error is thrown in the catch handler, the promise returned by catch is rejected, doesn't have a rejection handler, and generates the uncaught rejection error.

A solution would be to return the promise chain from `limitOrder` with suitable modifications to ensure it resolves with the corrrect value if successful:

```
async function limitOrder(keys, symbol, type, quantity, price, waitResult) {

  var client = await loadKeys(keys);
  return client.newOrder({
    symbol: symbol,
    side: type, //BUY OR SELL
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: quantity,
    price: price,
    timeInForce: "GTC",
    newOrderRespType: 'RESULT'
    })
   .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return {order: response, price: response.price, quantity: response.origQty}); //return back the order ID
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err); //print error if any
        reject(err);
    });
  });

}
```

The `.then` handler doesn't need to be declared as `async`if it is entirely synchronous. Obviously tt can be put back if it becomes necessary due to future modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `client.newOrder( ... )` method, you probably have another promise in there that throws an error in a `then` method, such as below:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  if ("type" in p) {

    Promise.resolve(1)
      .then((r) => {
      
        throw new Error('here is your uncatched error');
        
        resolve(r)
      })

  } else {
    reject(new Error('special fail')) // this is how to handle Errors
  }


})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated your code to use async/await instead of a promise and try-catch block to handle the error. Check it out:

```
async function limitOrder(keys, symbol, type, quantity, price, waitResult) {
  try {
    var client = await loadKeys(keys);
    let response = await client.newOrder({
      symbol: symbol,
      side: type,
      type: 'LIMIT',
      quantity: quantity,
      price: price,
      timeInForce: "GTC",
      newOrderRespType: 'RESULT'
    })
    console.log(response);
    return { order: response, price: response.price, quantity: response.origQty }; //return back the order ID
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err.message);
  };
}
```